# http.get not executed in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have a method that loads a text from a local `.txt` file in my `ngOnInit()`:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// This gets executed
console.log('FIRED');

this.http.get('assets/details.txt', {headers, responseType: 'text'})
    .pipe(
        map(data => {
            // This does not get executed!
            console.log('NOT FIRED');
        }),
        catchError((e: any) => {
            // Also no error Message
            console.log('NOT FIRED AS WELL');
            return throwError(e);
        }),
    );

    // This gets executed as well
    console.log('END');
```

Where is my mistake, how would I debug this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An observable is executed only when subscribed. `http.get` returns an observable. Modify your code as below

```
this.http.get('assets/details.txt', { headers, responseType: 'text' })
  .pipe(
    map(data => {
      // This does not get executed!
      console.log('NOT FIRED');
    }),
    catchError((e: any) => {
      // Also no error Message
      console.log('NOT FIRED AS WELL');
      return throwError(e);
    }),
  ).subscribe((response) => {
    // HTTP call success. Use response here
  }, (error) => {
    // HTTP call failed. Handle error
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you already add subscribe to your code ?

```
this.http.get('assets/details.txt', {headers, responseType: 'text'})
    .pipe(
        map(data => {
            // This does not get executed!
            console.log('NOT FIRED');
        }),
        catchError((e: any) => {
            // Also no error Message
            console.log('NOT FIRED AS WELL');
            return throwError(e);
        }),
    ).subscribe(); // here
```

As for documentation already mention

> Because the service method returns an Observable of configuration
>   data, the component subscribes to the method's return value. The
>   subscription callback copies the data fields into the component's
>   config object, which is data-bound in the component template for
>   display.

Answer (score 0):

Although @TonyNgo and @JohnsMathew are completely right, that the missing subscription is all you need in your case, i hope you wont just use your response there.
In most cases we are trying to pass around the observable instead of its outputs.
This is so each component which is using your data can react to changes via its own logic. 
So in your case you would most likely want to write something similar to:

ApiService.ts:

```
getDetails(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('assets/details.txt', {headers, responseType: 'text'});
}
```

SomeComponent.ts

```
constructor(private apiService ApiService) {}

someFunction() {
  const details$ = this.apiService.getDetails();
  details$.subscribe( detail => { 
    // execute all the things SomeComponent would need
  });
}
```